# Position icons over a button in a div

Tags: css

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| div                                                  |
|+----------------------------------------------------+|
|| button                                             ||
||                                      icon1 icon2   ||
||                                                    ||
|+----------------------------------------------------+|
|                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to place two icons over a button in a div, aligned center-right in the div. How do I write CSS for it?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your icons in a div and style that div like this

```
.wrapper-div{
    position:absolute;
    right:25px;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);

}
```

Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/zxt6azfn/

Comment: Thanks. I made it work without the transform. Why did you suggest it?

Comment: @artooras if you add the transform, it doesn't matter the height of the div, it will always be vertically centered

Answer (score 1):

You can try float property.

Sample:

```html
<div style="float:left">
    Button code
</div>
<div style="float:right">
    Icons code
</div>
```